# bluetoothlegatt: won´t find beacons

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am really new on programming.

I want to create an app, which can detect bluetooth beacons. I used bluetoothlegatt from the samples in android studio.

When i start the app it couldnt find my beacons.

Thank you in advance for help

Raymond

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't a tutorial site so there is some expectation that you can explain to the reader what you've tried. Unless you can describe what you've attempted and assumptions made (i.e. confirm that the beacons work, what devices are you testing on, errors seen, etc) no one can assist. It may help to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You might have better luck starting with a higher-level library like here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/

Comment: Thank you david. I tried this and thougt i could have a good start with this library. But the problem was, that i couldnt find out my beacon layout. I tried to google "setbeaconlayout" for the EMBC01 from EM but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Reactive Beacons](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveBeacons) Library for that. Using RxJava you can read multiple bluetooth devices in range as a stream and apply filter in few lines of code.

1. Add dependencies in your gradle.

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivebeacons:0.5.0'
   }
2. Sample code for your main Activity [can be found here](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveBeacons/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/pwittchen/reactivebeacons/app/MainActivity.java).